# Loading symboles for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Hos..[...] / Delay Notification (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, compilation

i install Visual Studio 2015 and I get the following message (at each debug / Round about 2 minutes).

[VS-Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYgNA.png)

What can I do? With VS 2013 I never got this message.

I use Windows 10 (64 bit).

Sorry for the short description... I can read and understand English very well but it is difficult for me to talk and write.

Thanks for all your help and answering!

Comment: It is because some antivirus might be blocking the `devenv.exe` process [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdxt2hcd.aspx) is the article about it and also a Issue was already raised at MSDN please look at the solution [Link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1770953/visual-studio-2015-windows-10-hang-with-delay-notification)

Comment: i deactivate my antivirus and add a exception zu the Windows firewall. No improvement... :(

Answer (score 0):

1. On the Tools menu, choose Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, open the Debugging node and then choose General.
3. Select Enable Just My Code.

Finish.

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio's **setup** and click **Repair**. It's a long process, but works. Also, check if you have updated the `Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools` extension to the latest version.